# How to fetch whole data from php and display it in html using AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to fetch data from PHP and display it in the table using Ajax.
I am unable to bring Whole data. I am getting only first row.
Here is my code.

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch.php',
        data: "",
        success: function(data) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });  
}
```

Here is my PHP code..!
from fetch.php

```
<?php 
    require_once 'db.php';
    $fetch = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $conn->query($fetch)->fetch_assoc();
    exit(json_encode($result));
?>
```

And here is my HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>NAme</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($all as $key) { ?>
       <tr>
           <td><?php echo $key['username']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $key['age']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $key['location']; ?></td>
       </tr>
   <?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: `fetch_assoc` fetches _one_ row out of the record set ... you want to use a _loop_ to go over _all_ records.

Comment: Using for each ??
Ok if i remove fetch_assoc() then how to iterate and send all tha data in a JSON and send it to AJAX ?
I am not getting sir.

Comment: Use fetchall instead ... or go read up on the more than trivial task of filling an array inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch_​assoc` fetches only one row, use `fetch_all` instead:

```
$result = $conn->query($fetch)->fetch_all();
```